My Buttons Work When Running The Script By Showing Their Respective Forms But When I Run It On A Local Server I Get A 404 Not Found When Clicked


function openCreateAccountForm() {
  // Dimensions for the popup window
  const width = 500;
  const height = 500;

  // Calculate the position to center the popup
  const left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
  const top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (height / 2);

  // Open the popup window with the calculated position
  window.open('../Forms/createAccount.html', 'popup', `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`);
}

function openSignInForm() {
  // Dimensions for the popup window
  const width = 500;
  const height = 500;

  // Calculate the position to center the popup
  const left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
  const top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (height / 2);

  // Open the popup window with the calculated position
  window.open('../Forms/signIn.html', 'popup', `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/background1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/signInPage.css">



<div class="musicContainer">
  <audio class="loungeMusic" controls loop>
            <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/l69tv279l3cn1ulzm4j0l/Enter-Friend.mp3?rlkey=76rteultp73bzlqn5si4m4mnx&st=gjl4htn9&dl=1" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
  <p class="loungeMessage">Press Play Too Lounge With Me</p>
</div>
<!-- Heading's Color ans size -->
<h1>

  <span class="welcome">Hello &amp; Welcome To:</span>
  <span class="redRat"> THE RED RAT'S ACRCHIVES </span>

</h1>


<!-- Paragraph text -->
<p class="welcomeMessage"> This is a collection containing the most popular browser games from all over the internet with games that are old and new. <br> I hope you will enjoy and share with your friends.<br> </p>
<br>
<p class="createAccountMessage"> Please sign in or create an account to access the website</p>

<!-- Log In Buttons-->
<div class="createAccountButton">
  <button onclick="openCreateAccountForm()" id="createAccount" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Create Account</button>
</div>

<div class="signInButton">
  <button onclick="openSignInForm()" id="signIn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Sign In</button>
</div>

<!-- Paragraph text -->
<p class="contactInfo"> email me at aidenf752@gmail.com with any feedback, recommendations, or errors you encounter </p>

<img class="pfp" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/pickle-rick-coming-out-of-portal-33vnk00t94f7eezj.jpg" alt="style" width="640">


<canvas id="projector" width="800" height="600"></canvas>





function validateForm(event) {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');

  if (username === '' || password === '') {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    errorMessage.textContent = 'Username and password cannot be empty';
  } else {
    errorMessage.textContent = ''; // Clear any previous error messages
  }
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1e374f;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(95, 17, 61);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #6f00ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<form method="post" action="../Databases/accountInfo.php" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
  <h2 style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Create Account</h2>
  <label style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required>

  <label style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>

  <div id="error-message" class="error"></div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



from flask import Flask, app, render_template, request, send_from_directory, render_template_string


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def signin():
    return render_template("signInPage.html")

@app.route('/Forms/createAccount')
def createAccount():
    return render_template('/Forms/createAccount.html')


I have made sure the file paths are correct and my the route directories in the app.py file included above are correct. I was expecting the createAccount form and sign in forms to appear respectively when the createAccount button and sign in buttons are clicked. It works when running the script but not on a local server

The form has action="../Databases/accountInfo.php", but the flask code only defines routes for / and /Forms/createAccount.

Please reduce your code to the minimum required. Do you really need to include the css, for example?

@LeeTaylor Yes, they really need a [mcve] which should include CSS in case it hides buttons or similar

PS: NEVER call anything "submit" in a form if you ever want to submit the form using script
